Which Kotlin-DSl version should I be using and where to find it
I am upgrading various libraries in my project, to include upgrading to Kotlin 2.0.0 and converting from Groovy to Kotlin-DSL for my gradle builds. When running a gradle build, it runs to a success, but when I run a build of the app, it gets the following message.
 Could not find org.gradle.kotlin.kotlin-dsl:4.4.0:.
Required by:
    project :app
Search in build.gradle files

Build file 'C:\Users\georg\AndroidStudioProjects\PeepsConnection\build.gradle.kts' line: 32

Plugin [id: 'org.gradle.kotlin.kotlin-dsl'] was not found in any of the following sources:

* Try:
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.plugins.UnknownPluginException: Plugin [id: 'org.gradle.kotlin.kotlin-dsl'] was not found in any of the following sources:

- Gradle Core Plugins (plugin is not in 'org.gradle' namespace)
- Included Builds (No included builds contain this plugin)
- Plugin Repositories (plugin dependency must include a version number for this source)
    at org.gradle.plugin.use.resolve.internal.PluginResolutionResult.getFound(PluginResolutionResult.java:112)
    at 
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.ClientProvidedPhasedActionRunner.run(ClientProvidedPhasedActionRunner.java:53)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
    at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.ProblemReportingBuildActionRunner.run(ProblemReportingBuildActionRunner.java:49)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildOutcomeReportingBuildActionRunner.run(BuildOutcomeReportingBuildActionRunner.java:65)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.FileSystemWatchingBuildActionRunner.run(FileSystemWatchingBuildActionRunner.java:140)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildCompletionNotifyingBuildActionRunner.run(BuildCompletionNotifyingBuildActionRunner.java:41)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RootBuildLifecycleBuildActionExecutor.lambda$execute$0(RootBuildLifecycleBuildActionExecutor.java:40)
    at org.gradle.composite.internal.DefaultRootBuildState.run(DefaultRootBuildState.java:123)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RootBuildLifecycleBuildActionExecutor.execute(RootBuildLifecycleBuildActionExecutor.java:40)
    at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.InitDeprecationLoggingActionExecutor.execute(InitDeprecationLoggingActionExecutor.java:66)
    at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.InitProblems.execute(InitProblems.java:36)
    at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.DefaultBuildTreeContext.execute(DefaultBuildTreeContext.java:40)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildTreeLifecycleBuildActionExecutor.lambda$execute$0(BuildTreeLifecycleBuildActionExecutor.java:71)
    at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.BuildTreeState.run(BuildTreeState.java:60)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildTreeLifecycleBuildActionExecutor.execute(BuildTreeLifecycleBuildActionExecutor.java:71)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionExecutor$3.call(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionExecutor.java:61)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionExecutor$3.call(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionExecutor.java:57)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:200)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:195)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:66)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:157)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.call(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:53)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:73)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionExecutor.execute(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionExecutor.java:57)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsWorkerThreadBuildActionExecutor.lambda$execute$0(RunAsWorkerThreadBuildActionExecutor.java:36)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.withLocks(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:264)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.runAsWorkerThread(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:128)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsWorkerThreadBuildActionExecutor.execute(RunAsWorkerThreadBuildActionExecutor.java:36)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.continuous.ContinuousBuildActionExecutor.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecutor.java:110)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SubscribableBuildActionExecutor.execute(SubscribableBuildActionExecutor.java:64)
    at org.gradle.internal.session.DefaultBuildSessionContext.execute(DefaultBuildSessionContext.java:46)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.BuildSessionLifecycleBuildActionExecuter$ActionImpl.apply(BuildSessionLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.java:92)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.BuildSessionLifecycleBuildActionExecuter$ActionImpl.apply(BuildSessionLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.java:80)
    at org.gradle.internal.session.BuildSessionState.run(BuildSessionState.java:71)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.BuildSessionLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.execute(BuildSessionLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.java:62)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.BuildSessionLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.execute(BuildSessionLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.java:41)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.execute(StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.java:64)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.execute(StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.java:32)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.execute(SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.java:51)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.execute(SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.java:39)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SetupLoggingActionExecuter.execute(SetupLoggingActionExecuter.java:47)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SetupLoggingActionExecuter.execute(SetupLoggingActionExecuter.java:31)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild.doBuild(ExecuteBuild.java:65)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:37)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.WatchForDisconnection.execute(WatchForDisconnection.java:39)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ResetDeprecationLogger.execute(ResetDeprecationLogger.java:29)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.execute(RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.java:35)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.create(ForwardClientInput.java:78)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.create(ForwardClientInput.java:75)
    at org.gradle.util.internal.Swapper.swap(Swapper.java:38)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput.execute(ForwardClientInput.java:75)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogAndCheckHealth.execute(LogAndCheckHealth.java:64)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient.doBuild(LogToClient.java:63)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:37)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment.doBuild(EstablishBuildEnvironment.java:84)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:37)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy$1.run(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:52)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator$1.run(DaemonStateCoordinator.java:297)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.AbstractManagedExecutor$1.run(AbstractManagedExecutor.java:47)




Everything I have read, has Kotlin-DSL 4.4.0 as the most recent version.
Any assistance here will be greatly appreciated.
Here is my settings.gradle.kts file.
pluginManagement {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        maven {
            url = uri("https://jitpack.io")
            url = uri("https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/")
            flatDir {
                dirs("libs")
            }
        }
        include(":app")
        rootProject.name = "CheckingIn"

    }


Here is my top level build.gradle.kts file
var kotlin_version = "2.0.0"
var roomVersion = "2.6.1"
var archLifecycleVersion = "2.2.0"
var coroutine_version = "1.8.0"
var hilt_version = "2.51.1"
var coreTestingVersion = "2.2.0"
var materialVersion = "1.2.1"
buildscript {
    val kotlin_version = "2.0.0"
    var coroutine_version = "1.8.0"
    repositories {
        gradlePluginPortal()
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        maven {
            url = uri("https://www.jitpack.io" )
            url = uri("https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/")
        }
        flatDir {
            dirs("libs")
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.5.0")
        classpath("com.google.gms:google-services:4.4.2")
        classpath("org.gradle.kotlin:gradle-kotlin-dsl-plugins:4.4.0")
        classpath("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-serialization:$kotlin_version")
    }

}

plugins {
    id ("org.gradle.kotlin.kotlin-dsl") version "4.4.0"
    id ("com.google.devtools.ksp") version "2.0.0-1.0.22" apply false
    id ("org.jetbrains.kotlin.android") version "2.0.0-Beta1" apply false
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        configurations.configureEach {
            maven {
                url = uri("https://www.jitpack.io" )
                url = uri("https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/")
                url = uri("https://com.github")
            }
            resolutionStrategy{
                force ("com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:20.0.0")
            }
        }

    }
}

Here is my app level build.gradle file.
plugins {
    id ("com.android.application")
    id ("kotlin-android")
    id ("com.google.gms.google-services")
    id ("org.jetbrains.kotlin.android")
    id ("kotlin-kapt")
    id ("com.google.devtools.ksp")

}
var work_version = "2.9.0"
var room_version = "2.6.1"
var kotlin_version = "2.0.0"
var roomVersion = "2.6.1"
var archLifecycleVersion = "2.2.0"
var coroutine_version = "1.8.0"
var hilt_version = "2.51.1"
var coreTestingVersion = "2.2.0"
var materialVersion = "1.2.1"
//apply plugin: 'com.google.dagger.hilt.android'
android {
    compileSdkVersion(34)
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId("com.grgmobilesolutions.peepsconnection")
        minSdkVersion(34)
        targetSdkVersion(34)
        versionCode(3)
        versionName("Beta 3.0.1")
        multiDexEnabled(true)
        testInstrumentationRunner("androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner")
    }
    buildTypes {
        getByName("release") {
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }

    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = 1.8
        targetCompatibility = 1.8
        kotlinOptions {
            jvmTarget=1.8
        }
    }
    namespace 'com.grgmobilesolutions.peepsconnection'

}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar','*.aar'])
    implementation "androidx.core:core:1.13.1"
    implementation "androidx.coordinatorlayout:coordinatorlayout:1.2.0"
    implementation "androidx.core:core-ktx:1.13.1"
    //implementation 'androidx.compose.material3:material3:1.2.1"
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.8.3"
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.8.0"
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.8.0"
    implementation "org.gradle.kotlin.kotlin-dsl:4.4.0"


    // (Java only)
    implementation "androidx.work:work-runtime:$work_version"
    // optional - Test helpers
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.work:work-testing:$work_version"

    // optional - Multiprocess support

    implementation "com.bugfender.sdk:android:3.2.0"

    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-appcheck-debug:18.0.0"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-appcheck-playintegrity:18.0.0"
    implementation "com.android.billingclient:billing:7.0.0"
    implementation "androidx.work:work-multiprocess:$work_version"
    implementation group: "org.locationtech.jts", name: "jts-core", version: "1.19.0"
    implementation "androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.7.0"
    implementation "androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4"
    implementation "com.google.android.material:material:1.12.0"
    implementation "androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0"
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:2.7.7"
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:2.7.7"
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.2.0"
    implementation "androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.3.2"
    implementation "com.vanniktech:emoji-google:0.7.0"
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:23.2.0"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:23.2.0"
    implementation "androidx.work:work-runtime:2.9.0"
    implementation "androidx.preference:preference-ktx:1.2.1"
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:19.0.0"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:23.0.0"
    implementation "androidx.annotation:annotation:1.8.0"
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:2.8.3"
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.8.3"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-database:21.0.0"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-functions:21.0.0"
    implementation "androidx.wear:wear:1.3.0"
    testImplementation "junit:junit:4.13.2"
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.test.ext:junit:1.2.1"
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.6.1"
    implementation "androidx.viewpager2:viewpager2:1.1.0"
    implementation "com.github.MikeOrtiz:TouchImageView:1.4.1" // last SupportLib version
    implementation platform("com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:33.1.1")
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:22.0.2"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:24.0.0"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-appcheck-playintegrity"
    implementation "com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:8.0.2"
    implementation "com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:8.0.2"
    implementation "com.google.android.material:material:1.12.0"
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:17.0.0"
    implementation "com.android.volley:volley:1.2.1"
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:21.3.0"
    implementation "androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1"
    implementation "com.google.android.libraries.maps:maps:3.1.0-beta"
    implementation "androidx.biometric:biometric:1.2.0-alpha05"

    implementation "com.google.auto.value:auto-value-annotations:1.10.4"
    implementation "com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:3.8.2"
    implementation "com.google.code.gson:gson:2.10.1"
    implementation "com.androidmapsextensions:android-maps-extensions:2.4.0"
    implementation "com.amulyakhare:com.amulyakhare.textdrawable:1.0.1"

    implementation("com.mikepenz:materialdrawer:5.9.5@aar") {
        transitive = true
        exclude group: "com.android.support"
    }
    implementation files("libs/activation.jar")
    implementation files("libs/additionnal.jar")
    implementation files("libs/mail.jar")
    kapt("androidx.hilt:hilt-compiler:1.2.0")
    kapt("com.google.dagger:hilt-compiler:$hilt_version")
    implementation("androidx.work:work-runtime-ktx:$work_version")
    // Room components
    ksp("androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version")
    implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:2.6.1"
    annotationProcessor "androidx.room:room-compiler:2.6.1"
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.room:room-testing:2.6.1"

    implementation "androidx.sqlite:sqlite:2.4.0"
    //implementation "net.zetetic:android-database-sqlcipher:4.5.3"
    implementation "net.zetetic:sqlcipher-android:4.5.5@aar"
    // Lifecycle components
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.2.0"
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-common-java8:2.8.3"
    //annotationProcessor "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-compiler:$rootProject.archLifecycleVersion"

    // UI
    implementation "com.google.android.material:material:1.12.0"

    // Testing
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.arch.core:core-testing:2.2.0"
    compileOnly "com.google.android.wearable:wearable:2.9.0"
}


Are you writing a Gradle plugin? As far as I'm aware, if you're just writing an Android application and want to change your Gradle build files to use the Kotlin DSL, you don't need to apply the kotlin-dsl plugin - just change your file name to build.gradle.kts and re-write its content in Kotlin. More info at https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/kotlin_dsl.html#sec:kotlin-dsl_plugin

That fixed it.  Thanks
